# Shadows in Three.js's Canvas renderer?

Tags: html5-canvas, three.js

As of r49, [Three.js](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/) does not support shadows in the Canvas renderer, right?

What I need is a shadow directly below an object, like if the light source was at infinite `y` (approximately sun at noon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can duplicate the object, set the `scale.y` to `0.001` and use a black color for the material :)

Comment: ...which is a workaround if the object receiving the shadow is a plane. In my case, it is not a plane, but geometry is still simple enough for a workaround. Anyway, I take it that shadows cannot be auto-generated by Three.js's Canvas renderer. Admittedly, if they were, it would have been a big surprise. Thanks for clarification!